# Pass JSON arrays aws api

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have this model Json schéma:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "title": "ArrayINPUT",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "QueryID": { "type": "integer" },
    "nR": { "type": "integer" },
    "Inarray": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "ids": { "type": "integer" },
          "contents": { "type": "string" }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I need to Pass this Inarray array with arrays ids and contents to api aws

And i dont know whats the format of this inArray?:"*?:*

```
Inarray [0,"sdasd",1,"sdfsdfsdfdgfd",2,"asdjkfbfgbsdhbfhsdfbg"........]
```

Something like this? or I have to create some special array and put into this array Object wich contains this 2 arrays:?

the output what i get: is empty Inarray

```
{
  "nR": "5",
  "Inarray": [],
  "QueryID": ""
}
```

My JSOn body mapping template:

```
#set($inputRoot = $input.path('$'))
{
  "QueryID" : "$input.params('QueryID')",
  "nR" : "$input.params('nR')",
  "Inarray" : [
##TODO: Update this foreach loop to reference array from input json
#foreach($elem in $input.params('Inarray'))
 {
    "ids" : "$elem.ids",
    "contents" : "$elem.contents"
  } 
#if($foreach.hasNext),#end
#end
]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are ignoring the $inputRoot variable (this is a velocity template).

I think you would be happier w/something like this:

```
#set($inputRoot) = $input.path('$'))
{
    "QueryID": "$inputRoot.QueryID",
    "nR": $inputRoot.nR,
    "Inarray": [
#foreach($elem in $inputRoot.Inarray)
{
    "ids":$elem.ids,
    "contents": "$elem.contents
}
#if($foreach.hasNext),#end
#end
]
}
```